# JW Player does not play videos automatically in playlist

Tags: jwplayer

I have a playlist. Videos in the playlist are from both Youtube and local server. First video is from local server and playback starts automatically. Second video is from Youtube and playback does not start automatically. I have to click on play. If the second video is also from local server it works fine.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Why do you want both videos to start together, user should see only one video, he wont be seeing both , Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me

```
<div id="playerContainer">
    <div id="player">jwplayer goes here...</div><br/><br/>
    <div id="player1">jwplayer goes here...</div>
</div>

jwplayer('player').setup({

            file: 'http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4',
            primary:'html5',
            stretching: 'exactfit',         
            autostart: true,
            height:240,
            width:360

        });     

jwplayer('player1').setup({

            file: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkMgJtb62zA',
            primary:'html5',
            stretching: 'exactfit',         
            autostart: true,
            height:240,
            width:360

        });
```

Check [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hiteshbhilai2010/6YyXH/70/)